# filtering elements in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to filter data, in this case, the sex of a group of people, and then calculating the mean of the age of only the people who are mail (previously filtered).

```
average_age_men = df.loc[df["sex" == "Male"], df["age".mean()]]
print(average_age_men)
```

This code here should work but keeps throwing the same mistake, KeyError: False (I already checked the post referred to that error). I have no clue of what to do, I feel like it's actually so simple that I feel silly for not being able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is (probably):

```
average_age_men = df.loc[df["sex"] == "Male", "age"].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
average_age_men = df[df["sex"] == "Male"]]["age"].mean()
```

Comment: You're right, but when you find yourself doing `df["column"][some_index]` OR `df[condition]["column"]` (i.e., two bracket indexings), you should use `.loc` instead, like @Corralien did: `df.loc[some_index, "column"]` and `df.loc[condition, column]`. It's cleaner-looking and probably faster. Plus: you'll get fewer `SettingWithCopy` warnings because I think you can assign directly to those `.loc` statements, whereas you can't with the two bracket indexings.